# Google Sheets - Find the lowest values in the entire table line by line

Tags: google-sheets, min, array-formulas, flatten, google-query-language

I can't find a way to make ArrayFormula and SMALL functions work together using the built-in Google sheets functions.

[I have a table1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JH7FF11rXZRQHrpAfR4WvsTNQdVqwMrIQDhVEH5z3Eo/edit#gid=0) with items and their prices. Each position has the lowest price with SMALL function, but when you add a new row, the formula breaks.

If you roughly add an ArrayFormula (table2), SMALL looks for the lowest value in the entire table, not line by line.

I've tried different combinations of VLOOKUP, ROW, INDEX, but can't solve the puzzle.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? Or..... ?  It is a but unclear WHERE you add this new row, when you say: "...but when you add a new row..."

Comment: When I add Position 3.5 (between Position 3 and Position 4), and set prices, the formula for calculating the lowest price in the row does not work in the new row until I expand it.

Comment: I think (but am not sure of it) you are having the same question as this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287554/google-sheets-automatically-apply-formula-to-new-rows-added-at-the-top) ?  But unfortunately is has not an accepted answer, and I do not know the answer too 

Comment: In case you're wondering, the answer to that question is the formula for C1
={"Tax";arrayformula(B2:B/10)}

My problem is a little more complicated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(D14:O); 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(","; 1; IF(B14:B="";;
 "min(Col"&ROW(B14:B)-ROW(B14)+1&")"))));; 2)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(F14:F)&"×"&OFFSET(F14;;;9^9; 9^9)); "×");
 "select min(Col2) 
  group by Col1  
  label min(Col2)''"))
```

[image]

Comment: This formula works fine for a small array. But I have ~300 rows and ~30 columns and it doesn't work with such an array(


Example on Sheet2. Columns:
- "INDEX" is your formula, 
- "SMALL" is the SMALL function as a reference, 
- "INDEX +TO_TEXT" - I added TO_TEXT to your formula.


What's interesting, when you add TO_TEXT, some of the values count correctly, some don't.

Comment: @ДмитрийГородничин answer and your sheet updated

Comment: I don't know how, but it works very well. Thank you, good man!